# Noise reduction for audio buffer as it gets filled in

Tags: audio, noise-reduction

I have a scenario where some audio is being received over the internet. The audio itself has lot of noise, which needs to be filtered out. Received audio is raw PCM 16 bit.

Tools like audacity can remove noise, but they create a noise profile and then remove the noise from part of or from the whole file. I want to instead remove noise from the audio as it comes in and gets written to a buffer, so that once all the audio is received and written to the buffer, noise reduction is already completed and the audio can be played out. Each packet from the network sends around 1 KB of audio, and the total audio is around 1 MB.

The audio contains conversation between two people, so I want to keep the audio within voice recording range (80-255 Hz from the comments).

I want to ask if anyone knows of any algorithm that can achieve this.

Comment: You'll need to add more information to this question.  There are filtering algorithms that can work, but they are application specific.  For instance, voice recordings tend to [fall in the 80-255 hz range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_frequency), so you could filter out frequencies below and above that, or use an adaptive technique (seems to be an area of [current research](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_an_algorithm_to_separate_human_voice_from_background_music_in_a_song)).  Of course, if your goal is to detect gunshots, then the algorithm would necessarily be different.

Comment: You'll have to define "noise" before you can remove it. High frequency hiss? Low frequency rumbling? Random, one sample transients?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer The audio is a voice recording done outdoors so I want to remove everything but the human voice in the audio.

Comment: 80-255Hz is a really low and really narrow range for voice audio.  At best all you'd be picking up is the fundamental and first harmonic.  Telephone typically transmits at least 300Hz-3kHz, because the content of the human voice in that range is much more important.  Aside from that, common solutions are a noise gate and spectral filters.  What you describe as an unacceptable answer from Audacity is a spectral gate, so perhaps you should look into a noise gate?

Comment: @MikeSperry If you could provide some link to some existing algo that perform spectral and noise gate, then that would be helpful. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Jake mathworks has a good description of a dynamic range noise gate (I haven't used matlab in years, but I still often find their pages very useful) https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/noisegate.html